# Getting the id of the last record inserted into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the id of the last record inserted into a MySQL database using `MAX(id)`.
I can't figure out why my query is not returning any results. Is there something wrong with my PHP?Tthe query works if I try it inside phpmyadmin.

```
include("db_conx.php"); //Connect to db mysqli
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl_uploads";  
$result = $db_conx->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo 'last_id: '.$row['id'];
```

Comment: `print_r($row);` will show you. Also `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');` would have led you there.

Comment: Do a print of result variable. Is it true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an alias for get  the value

```
  $sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM tbl_uploads";  
  $result = $db_conx->query($sql);
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  echo 'last_id: '.$row['max_id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX(id) as id` in select query

```
include("db_conx.php"); //Connect to db mysqli
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM tbl_uploads";  
$result = $db_conx->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo 'last_id: '.$row['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this built in function for get last insert id

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

if you want to get max record id from your db and if id this your primary key then you can use this code

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_uploads order by id desc";  
$result = $db_conx->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo 'last_id: '.$row['id'];
```

and if you want to get specific max record then use this code. if id your filed then you can use this code . you use alias for get record

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM tbl_uploads";  
$result = $db_conx->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo 'last_id: '.$row['max_id'];
```

Comment: This won't work.  OP wants to fetch records not insert

Comment: ok i am adding this too

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FRON tbl_uploads ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

It will output your id.